# PropertyEditor not for Type conversion but String manipulation

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm feeling kinda lost when it comes to String type with Property editors and string transformation. PropertyEditors and Conversion services are based on type of properties. But what about when it is needed to transform string to a different string ? If the field is of Date type, CustomDatePropertyEditor is applied, the conversion will be always the same, String to Date, but if we want to convert string A to string B, then we want it to happen only to a particular field, but it would do that for all fields of type String. There is no way of saying which field to convert / transform by this PropertyEditor.

For instance, I'm getting 1 or 0 request parameters from a UI html form widget and I'd need to bind it to a bean as PM or AM. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "field1", new PropertyEditorSupport() { });
}
```

that way it only applies to `"field1"` of type `String`.

Comment: Omg you're right, I was looking at this method x times and I always missed this possibility, thanks man

Comment: Are you using SpringMVC? The following is a method for Binding in the constructor. The code is of course from Spring 3 and Spring MVC 3. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I can't believe it, I stuck on this one for almost an hour, searching through the entire framework :-)